# Downloading just one image from a server that keeps sending them

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl

There is a server that sends images from a CCTV. The data looks like the following:

```
--BoundaryString
Content-type: image/jpeg
Content-Length:       15839
... first image in binary...
--BoundaryString
Content-type: image/jpeg
Content-Length:       15895
... second image in binary...
```

and so on (it continues indefinitely). I was trying pyCurl to fetch just one image like so:

```
curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(curl.URL, 'http://localhost:8080')
with open('image.jpg', 'w') as fd:
    curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, fd.write)
    curl.perform()
```

but it doesn't stop after one image and it continues to read from the server. Is there a way to tell curl to stop after one part?

Alternatively, I could just use a socket and implement a simple GET / myself. That's not a problem. However I'm wondering if it's possible to use pyCurl for this case and I'd also like to know what this is since it doesn't look like a proper multipart message to me.

The server is something called "motion" (a video motion detection daemon for Linux).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code that works for me. (python 2)
This will get you all the images sent by the server. if you only need one, `sys.exit(0)` after you saved the image.

```
from functools import partial
import socket


def readline(s):
    fx = partial(s.recv, 1)
    ret = [x for x in iter(fx, '\n')]
    return ''.join(ret)


def main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8080))

    while True:
        line = readline(s)
        if line.rstrip('\r') == '--BoundaryString':
            content_type = readline(s)
            length = int(readline(s).rstrip('\r').split()[-1])
            _ = readline(s)  # we skip an empty line
            image = ''
            while length:
                data = s.recv(length)  # here is receiving only 1375 bytes even if you tell it more
                length -= len(data)  # so we decrement and retry
                image += data
            # print repr(image[:20])  # was for debug
            # TODO --> open a file and save the image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```